# What HTML or CSS code can I use so that an image/text is viewable on the mobile site only and not desktop?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

On my wordpress site, I want to insert and image that should be visible only when viewed on on a mobile device and not on a desktop. What CSS/HTML code can I use here?

```
<div class="mobile-only"><a href="MY_URL"> TEXT/IMAGE </a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into viewports. Then you could add a viewport for mobile versions.

Something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .your-image-div{
display:none
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){
    .your-image-div{
display:block
}
}
```